# Error al ejecutar query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

No me había ocurrido hasta que quise realizar un chat con php y ajax, yo se que un chat es mejor realizarlo con otros lenguajes, pero este no demanda la robustez como para usar los otros lenguajes.

Mi query que estoy intentando hacer es el siguiente, este es solo para hacer una tipo notificacion donde muestra el último mensaje que ha recibido la persona y la imprime en pantalla

```
    function obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us) {
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS m.idEmitter, m.nombre, m.message, m.sent, m.idReceiver
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN (SELECT idEmitter, idReceiver, max(idChat) AS idChat
FROM messages
WHERE seenEmpresa = 0
GROUP BY idEmitter, idReceiver) mm
ON m.idChat = mm.idChat
AND m.idEmitter = mm.idEmitter
AND m.idReceiver = mm.idReceiver
WHERE m.idReceiver = $us
AND seenEmpresa = 0");
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetchAll();
}

@$emit = obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us);
```

El error lo genera la variable $emit

El error que me sale en pantalla es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\functions.php:111 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\functions.php(126): obtener_mensajes(NULL, '3') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez
>
> empresa\index.php(4): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\functions.php on line 111

En la línea 111 que menciona es la línea del prepare de mi query

Este es el resultado que debería aparecer, ya que es el que aparece en mi gestor de base de datos `HeidiSQL`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llamada a la función de conexion

```
function conexion($bd_config) {
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $bd_config['basedatos'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['pass']);
        return $conexion;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

$bd_config
 proviene de otro fichero

```
$bd_config = array(
    'basedatos' => 'nombre',
    'usuario' => 'nombre',
    'pass' => 'pass',
);
```

Comment: deberias mostrar como llamas a esta funcion.. pero seguro, conexion esta en nulo, nunca la inicializaste

Comment: @gbianchi acabo de editar con la funcion de conexion y como es mandada a llamar conexion la mando a llamar por medio de una funcion en el archivo functions.php

Comment: @gbianchi he encontrado el error, pero no se como solucionarlo, y lo necesito de esa manera para el chat que cree, editarea el post

Comment: Prueba a ver que te está devolviendo el error, ejecutando un **print_r($e);** antes del return false del catch. Da la sensación de que no puedes acceder por localhost, o que MySQL no te permite acceder. Por un casual la app y el MySQL están en servidores distintos?

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\functions.php:111

Al parecer, $conexion tiene un valor nulo y no el enlace de conexión a base de datos.

Antes de **$emit**, asegúrate que **$conexion** y **$us** tienen un valor adecuado.

No uses @ para ocultar mensajes de error, eso solo te va a complicar la depuración de tus scripts.

Finalmente, tienes y try-catch para conectar a la base de datos, pero si algo falla, ahí debe terminar el script, puesto que se trata de un error crítico y que, seguramente, impedirá que funcione todo lo demás.